# TSQL Option Where with CASE Statement

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a basic query that is used for getting search results based on the filter options that were selected on the UI.

In my table, I have a date column called expirationDate which is the date a document expires (doesnt do anything, just used for reference).

Well, in the UI, there is an option to select the status you want to see; either Expired or Active.

Based on which one you choose, I need to alter the query but not sure how to go about it since its relating to a date and not just a status column it has to check against.

In the query below, if status = Active, I need to add to the `WHERE` clause so that the expirationDate has not passed today's date (meaning it hasn't expired). However, If I choose expired, I need the `WHERE` clause include anything where the expirationDate has not yet passed today's date (Active Items).

```
IF(@employee = '') SET @employee = NULL;
IF(@supervisor = '') SET @supervisor = NULL;
IF(@manager = '') SET @manager = NULL;
IF(@location = '') SET @location = NULL;
IF(@skillset = '') SET @skillset = NULL;
IF(@category = '') SET @category = NULL;
IF(@type = '') SET @type = NULL;
IF(@status = '') SET @status = NULL;

    SELECT recordID,
           employeeQID,
           firstName,
           lastName,
           department,
           location,
           supervisorQID,
           supervisorFirstName,
           supervisorLastName,
           managerQID,
           managerFirstName,
           managerLastName,
           documentationType,
           documentationCategory,
           CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), startDate, 101) AS startDate,
           CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), expirationDate, 101) AS expirationDate,
           notes,
           skillset,
           timestamp,
           creator
    FROM   dbo.documentation_records
    WHERE  (@employee IS NULL OR (employeeQID = @employee))
    AND    (@supervisor IS NULL OR (supervisorQID = @supervisor))
    AND    (@manager IS NULL OR (managerQID = @manager))
    AND    (@location IS NULL OR (location = @location))
    AND    (@skillset IS NULL OR (skillset = @skillset))
    AND    (@category IS NULL OR (documentationCategory = @category))
    AND    (@type IS NULL OR (documentationType = @type))
    FOR    XML PATH ('results'), TYPE, ELEMENTS, ROOT ('root');
```

What is the best way to handle this while also allowing the status to be `NULL` and ignored if not chosen as a filter option in the UI like I have done with the other `vars`.

Comment: **Dynamic SQL** is the answer, have a look at the answer provided to this question, [`Dynamic Filters in SQL server`](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/108903/dynamic-filters-in-sql-server/108908#108908)

Comment: Here is an excellent article on this type of query. http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/

Comment: @M.Ali You do not need Dynamic SQL for this, Dynamis SQL is overkill for a few OR and AND statements

Answer (score -1):

```
        ((@status = '' 
     OR  @status IS NOT NULL && @STATUS = 'ACTIVE' AND EXPIRATIONDATE > GETDATE() )
     OR (@status IS NOT NULL && @STATUS = 'expired' AND EXPIRATIONDATE < GETDATE()))
```

the above is the added code to your where clause. It does this.

**EDIT **
The first or clause will return everything if status isnt passed in.

the `||` is what is going to get you there. You want everything that isnt NULL, IS ACTIVE, AND ISNT EXPIRED `OR` everything that isnt NULL, IS EXPIRED, AND HAS THE EXPIRATION DATE PASSED.

```
IF(@employee = '') SET @employee = NULL;
IF(@supervisor = '') SET @supervisor = NULL;
IF(@manager = '') SET @manager = NULL;
IF(@location = '') SET @location = NULL;
IF(@skillset = '') SET @skillset = NULL;
IF(@category = '') SET @category = NULL;
IF(@type = '') SET @type = NULL;
IF(@status = '') SET @status = NULL;

    SELECT recordID,
           employeeQID,
           firstName,
           lastName,
           department,
           location,
           supervisorQID,
           supervisorFirstName,
           supervisorLastName,
           managerQID,
           managerFirstName,
           managerLastName,
           documentationType,
           documentationCategory,
           CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), startDate, 101) AS startDate,
           CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), expirationDate, 101) AS expirationDate,
           notes,
           skillset,
           timestamp,
           creator
    FROM   dbo.documentation_records
    WHERE  (@employee IS NULL OR (employeeQID = @employee))
    AND    (@supervisor IS NULL OR (supervisorQID = @supervisor))
    AND    (@manager IS NULL OR (managerQID = @manager))
    AND    (@location IS NULL OR (location = @location))
    AND    (@skillset IS NULL OR (skillset = @skillset))
    AND    (@category IS NULL OR (documentationCategory = @category))
    AND    (@type IS NULL OR (documentationType = @type))
    AND    (
                    (@status = ''
 OR @status IS NOT NULL AND @STATUS = 'ACTIVE' AND EXPIRATIONDATE > GETDATE() )
                 OR (@status IS NOT NULL AND @STATUS = 'expired' AND EXPIRATIONDATE < GETDATE())
                )
        FOR    XML PATH ('results'), TYPE, ELEMENTS, ROOT ('root');
```

Comment: This works with one exception .. A status is required for it to run at all. If I don't pass anything in the status (its optional in the UI) then nothing is returned. There are situations where I don't care what the status is, I just want to see everything for the employee Jim Bob.

Comment: added an aditional or clause to make sure if a status is empty that everything is returned

Comment: Since when we can use `|` in sql server expressions ?

Comment: @m.Ali oh ffs, If you are not competent enough to replace the || with OR. dont program.
Also your comment and probably downvote is stupid, because | can be used as a bitwise OR since sql 2005   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186714.aspx

Comment: @gh9 your comment that we do not need dynamic sql for this query speaks for itself and I have a pretty good idea about HOW competence ARE YOU. Your suggested method will result in horrible execution plan and probably a very **incompetent**  execution plan, google about optional parameters in SQL Server and educate yourself.

Comment: Also all of these NOTs, Ands & ORs put together without any parenthesis could you please explain what predicate will take precedence over what ???  `@status = '' OR @status IS NOT NULL AND @STATUS = 'ACTIVE' AND EXPIRATIONDATE > GETDATE()`